# PyMySql isnt working and dont wanna connect

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I wanna connect to the mysql but it isnt working. all is correct but pymysql dont wanna do this.

My Code is:

```
connection1 = pymysql.connect(
    host='host'
    user='user'
    passwd='password'
    db='database'
)
```

It says:

```
    user='IM NOT SHOWING THE USERNAME'
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me? I wanna do this.

Comment: you missed comma `,`. They are separated by `,`

Answer (score 1):

Missing commas here:

```py
connection1 = pymysql.connect(
    host='host',
    user='user',
    passwd='password',
    db='database'
)
```

Comment: it says `([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")`

Comment: You must to set the appropriate settings after..

Comment: what appropriate settings..? @9414882

Comment: this answer meets your need, on Stack Overflow you should search your issue, and if not find open a new question. Open only one question per issue.

Comment: He's meaning you need to replace `host` `user` etc with the correct values. If you have and it still won't connect, then that is something you'll need a new question for.